# How would single sign-on work for my multi-tenant application?

Tags: laravel, oauth, single-sign-on, multi-tenant, laravel-passport

I need help understanding how to 'think' about single sign-on for my multi-tenant application. I've tried ChatGPT for explanation; but I think my fellow humans can do a much better job.

Here's what I'm building:

A laravel application that allows customers to create `subdomain.example.com` and then run it on their own domain `subdomain.customer-app.com` by pointing CNAME record.

I'd like to authenticate the users of `customer-app.com` when they visit `subdomain.customer-app.com` automatically. That is, when they are logged-in to `customer-app.com`; they are automatically logged-in to `subdomain.customer-app.com` (which is running `subdomain.example.com` behind the scenes).

My laravel app is ready; but I'm unable to figure out how would authentication work in this setup. Reading the Laravel Passport documentation has not helped; because I'm not able to figure out how the information exchange works in the above scenario.

Would really appreciate it if a good soul can help me figure this out. Thank you in advance.